# Grails web flow: Possible to include the state name in the url?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I'm playing around with [Google Analytics goals / funnels](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55580). I would like to use this to track a checkout process, but the web flow urls are formated in a way that makes this very hard.

Would it be possible to change:
http://localhost:8080/checkout/checkout?execution=e1s2

.. into something more like this:
http://localhost:8080/checkout/checkout/shipping?execution=e1s2

or any thing else that would make them more trackable with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know whether it's possible to format web flow urls differently, but I found a solution to my problem:

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en_US&answer=55514&utm_id=ad

Comment: It's funny how answers are coming in when the problem is solved or a workaround is in place :-) 

It's apparently possible to change the url format by providing a custom flowUrlHandler:
http://n4.nabble.com/Web-flow-Possible-to-include-the-state-name-in-the-url-td1773803.html#a1773954